# Participle clauses with different subjects

Tags: participle-clauses

I saw other phrases like
Tom doing the homework, Jane cleaned her room.

But I'm not sure with this sentence:
He doing the homework, Jane cleaned her room.

Is it possible to have pronoun in subject form as the subject in participle phrase?

Comment: Please quote the sentences you actually saw. None of those is good English

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your sentences is correct English. You could say

*While Tom was doing his homework, Jane cleaned her room*.

If Tom was mentioned in the previous sentence, so we know who you are talking about, you could say *While he was doing his homework...* instead.

Answer (score 0):

> *Tom doing the homework, Jane cleaned her room.*

It's acceptable if "He doing the homework" is intended to be an adjunct of implicated reason, i.e. the adjunct gives the reason for the matrix situation (Jane cleaning her room).

Yes, a subjective pronoun is fine, as is an objective one: "He/him doing the homework ...".